# Android. What is wrong during reading from file?

Tags: android, file-io

```
public class ReadFromFile extends Activity{

    public String readFromFile(String file) {

        String ret = "";

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(file);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("File not found: ", "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Can not read file: ", "");
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

---

```
03-09 22:17:56.181: W/dalvikvm(14108): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40caf450)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:159)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at com.example.anewapp.ReadFromFile.readFromFile(ReadFromFile.java:19)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at com.example.anewapp.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:287)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
03-09 22:17:56.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14108):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Null reference at line number 19

Comment: But why? When I tried separately the code everything worked, in an activity does not.

Comment: is that the whole Activity code that you posted?

Comment: Why not just check the line or post it here?

Comment: No, this is the class what reading from file. The line 19th:InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(file);

Comment: what do you mean with this is just the class that reads the file? It is an activity class which has to obey activity lifecycle. So you either start that activity at some point or you have other activities extending this activity at some point. For both cases there is code missing in your activity class.

Comment: I call this class from an activity.

Comment: ReadFromFile clr = new ReadFromFile();                                     String input = clr.readFromFile("setting.txt");

Comment: you should not instantiate activities like this `new ReadFromFile("setting.txt");`  in android

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: @user3399567 see my answer, I think that should prevent the NPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

let your MainActivity **extend** ReadFromFile:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReadFromFile {
```

And then **call readFromFile method** simply like this

```
readFromFile("setting.txt");
```

instead of:

```
ReadFromFile clr = new ReadFromFile();   
String input = clr.readFromFile("setting.txt");
```

Note: I also suggest renaming `ReadFromFile` to `ReadFileActiviy` to make it more clear that it is an activity

Comment: I can`t extend because the activity where I called the the class is extended with "Activity".

Comment: You _can_! Because your ReadFromFile extends Activity as well. Just do it ;-)